# Grouping unique values with low value counts

Tags: python

My Data frame contains over 40 unique values for a particular attribute. I want to do some visualisation of this data, but fitting in all 40 points is challenging. Using `wine['country'].value_counts()`, I can see the frequency of each unique value.

[image]

When I go to create, for example, a bar chart, I would like any unique values with value counts less than 100 to be grouped together to create it's own bar in the visualisation (and say call it 'rest' or 'other').

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a variable `x = 0`.Iterate through `wine['country'].value_counts()` using `for` loop. Then check if a particular `value_counts()` is less than 100, if true, then add the `value_counts()` value for that particular iteration to `x`. This way you will have the sum of such values whose count is less than 100.
Now before charting, create a new dataframe having data of `country` vs `value_counts()` with only those rows whose `value_counts()` value is greater than 100. Then manually add another row named `'other'` to this new dataframe with its `value_counts()` as `x`. Use this new dataframe for charting.

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Khare, would you be able to provide the code to do this?